# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, iis-6, .net-2.0, windows-server-2003

I am getting following Error when I tried to extract .cab file using "cablib.extract.extractFiles" method. 
I am using 
windows server 2003 sp2,
.net 2.0, 
iis 6.0 and 
cablib.dll version is 8.1.0.0

Error is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Source Error: 


Line 2205:
Line 2206:                        string strFilePath = strTmpCabPath + "\\" + strFile;
Line 2207:                        i_Extract.ExtractFile(strFilePath, strTempDir);
Line 2208:
Line 2209:                        string XmlPath = Server.MapPath(CCommon.COMMON_RESOURCE_FILE_XML);


Source File: d:\wwwroot\WebPages\FileUpload.aspx.cs    Line: 2207 

Stack Trace: 


[AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.]
   new(UInt32 ) +0
   CUtf7.Encode(CUtf7* , UInt16* u16_In) +232
   CExtractT<CExtract>.SetDecryptionKeyW(CExtractT<CExtract>* , UInt16* u16_DecryptKey) +78
   CabLib.Extract.ExtractFile(String s_CabFile, String s_Folder) +243
   FileUpload.WriteToDatabase(String strFileName, Byte[] arrFileBytes) in d:\wwwroot\WebPages\FileUpload.aspx.cs:2207
   FileUpload.FileUploadFunc(String strFilePath, String strFileName, Boolean bOtherDocs) in d:\wwwroot\WebPages\FileUpload.aspx.cs:2530
   FileUpload.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\wwwroot\WebPages\FileUpload.aspx.cs:982
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618
```

Comment: What is i_Extract.ExtractFile(strFilePath, strTempDir);?  How is it defined?

Comment: Are we meant to guess what code produced this trace? Because if that's your intention you won't get much help.

Comment: What is your question? It may be easy to guess it, but still you should state it explicitly.

Comment: Contact the library owner for support.

Comment: i_Extract is the instance of Cablib.Extract class